# SQLAlchemy: get Index object for a given column with index=True

Tags: python, indexing, sqlalchemy

How can I get an SQLAlchemy `Index` object corresponding to a column that has `index=True`?

For example, in the code below, I'd like to have the `Index` associated to `MyTable.name`.

```py
from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeBase, Mapped, mapped_column

class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass

class MyTable(Base):
    __tablename__ = "my_table"
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(index=True)
```

The end purpose is to call `Index.drop()`, insert a lot of rows at once, and `Index.create()` afterwards, for performance reasons.

I could do `session.execute(text(drop index ...))` but I don't know what the name of the index is. If there's a way to get the index name without generating the `Index` object, that'd be fine too.

(I'm using SQLAlchemy 2.0)

Comment: Assuming that the table actually exists, you should be able to do `from sqlalchemy import inspect; insp = inspect(engine); index_info = insp.get_indexes(MyTable.__tablename__)`. That should return something like `[{'name': 'ix_my_table_name', 'column_names': ['name'], 'unique': 0, 'dialect_options': {}}]`

Comment: @python_user yeah I think I got a little confused, not sure how I did not realize this answered my question...

Comment: I think I was hoping for something more obvious like `MyTable.name.get_index()` but whatever, this is good enough. And in the meantime I've also found `MyTable.__table__.indexes` which is even better. So yeah sorry for wasting your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some additional research here's a solution for future reference. A bit convoluted but it works.

The main point is that you can use `MyTable.__table__.indexes` to get a set of all indexes available on `MyTable`. Then it's just a matter of finding which one is mapped to `MyTable.name`.

```py
def get_name_index():
    """Return Index object for MyTable.name."""

    def get_name_column():
        """Return imperative Column object for MyTable.name."""
        for column in MyTable.__table__.c:
            if column.name == MyTable.name.name:
                return column

    name_column = get_name_column()
    for index in MyTable.__table__.indexes:
        if index.c == [name_column]:
            return index
```

(If there's a way to replace `get_name_column()` by something simpler, please let me know!)